# Java applet giving AccessControlException

Tags: java, applet, accesscontrolexception, appletviewer

I have a Java applet which I am trying to run within an HTML file using HTML applet tag
`<applet>`, but it is throwing the following exception:

```
Caused by: java.security.AccessControlException: access denied 
    (java.io.FilePermission darkorange.png read)
```

Oracle site has explained giving access to applets using policy like:

```
appletviewer -J-Djava.security.policy=applet
```

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/security/tour1/examples/WriteFile.html

But that is only in DOS, how do I make my browser recognize the security file?

Comment: What is `darkorange.png`?  Is it an image used by the app. itself?

Comment: yes it is an image used by the program.the applet works fine in eclipse , but in browser it gives this exception , i know it can be done as amazon s3 use a java applet to load files from client machine to server, just uable to figure out how

Answer (score 0):

Applets cannot read/write files from local machine and/or connect/read/write from/to a domain different from the one it was loaded from. They are restricted to a sandbox-like environment and need permission to access system resources outside their restricted environment. Applets are restricted to read operations within their local directory. All other access operations require permission. I would suggest to revisit your requirement of reading a file from a client machine as this is apparently isn't a valid requirement.

BTW, if you need to do it anyways, then your applet jars has to be [signed](http://java.sun.com/developer/onlineTraining/Programming/JDCBook/signed.html) and relevant permissions should be granted to your applet in the user java.policy file on the client machine. Refer to the java documentation for specifying the policy.

Comment: Hi finally after three days i have solved it , there are two parts to the problem. one is two place code which access files on client machines inside doprivileged method, second is to sign the jar http://www.raditha.com/java/sandbox/unsigned.php This page did the rescue